# Django Associations with the user model

Tags: django, authentication, associations, relation

How can I associate lists apps Listing model with an user. User has_many lists.

What shall I include in my List model for being able to use models.ForeignKey(User)

Comment: not sure if i get the question: lists apps Listing Model? what do you mean exactly, give me some more information code snippets etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go (Although you should just look at the Django DOcs the next Time):

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Listing(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

Hope this helps